# How can I compile atom code through terminal using truffle?

Tags: truffle

I trying to compile my atom code through the Mac terminal and I received this error:

```
Error parsing /Users/owner/Desktop/contracts/contracts/ApprovalContracts.sol: ParsedContract.sol:6:36: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
address public constant approver = ;                  ^
Compilation failed. See above.
```

I need to compile my code from atom using the terminal `truffle compile`.

Here is the code:

```html
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ApprovalContracts {

address public sender;
address public receiver;
address public constant approver =;

function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
 require(msg.value > 0);
 sender = msg.sender;
 receiver = receiver;
}

function viewApprover() external pure return(address)  {
return(approver);
}

function approve() external {
require(msg.sender == approver);
receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. You have to initialize the constant variable `approver` with a value.
2. On line 12, the code should be `receiver = _receiver;`
3. On line 15, it should be `returns(address)` instead of `return(address)`

The final code should be something like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ApprovalContracts {

    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    address public constant approver=some-address-here-without-quotes;

    function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
    }

    function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The code provided is correct and answers the question.